How to compare uid nfc to csv database (tag :Mifare DESFire : ISO14443-4 : Type A, Isodep)
my app launch but nothing happened when i put a nfc tag.
The goal is normally simple, put nfc tag, compare uid to a csv database.
The Mifare DESFire : ISO14443-4 : Type A, Isodep Tag contains secured certificates as the card is used in a company and the only open thing is the UID.
mainactivity.kt :
package com.example.simplicims

import android.nfc.NfcAdapter
import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.nfc.Tag
import android.nfc.tech.NfcA
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.FileReader
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStream
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory

class MainActivity : Activity() {

    private lateinit var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter
    private lateinit var uidTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var statusTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var scanButton: Button

    private val validUids = mutableListOf<String>()  // List to store valid UIDs from CSV

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        uidTextView = findViewById(R.id.uidTextView)
        statusTextView = findViewById(R.id.statusTextView)
        scanButton = findViewById(R.id.scanButton)

        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)

        // Check for permissions and load CSV file
        checkPermissions()

        scanButton.setOnClickListener {
            // Trigger NFC scan manually if needed
            // Optionally, start an activity for NFC scan manually
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)

        if (NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this) == null) {
            statusTextView.text = "NFC non dispo"
            return
        } else {
            if (nfcAdapter.isEnabled) {
                Log.e("NFC", "NFC is disabled")
            } else {
                nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, null, null, null)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED == intent?.action) {
            val tag: Tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)!!
            val uid = tag.id.joinToString("") { it.toString(16).padStart(2, '0') }
            uidTextView.text = "UID: $uid"
            checkUidInDatabase(uid)
        }
    }

    private fun loadCsvDatabase() {
        try {
            val csvFile = File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/database.csv") // CSV file path
            if (!csvFile.exists()) {
                statusTextView.text = "CSV file not found"
                return
            }

            val reader = BufferedReader(FileReader(csvFile))
            var line: String?

            while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                // Assuming each line contains a single UID
                val uid = line?.trim() // Remove any unnecessary whitespace
                if (!uid.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    validUids.add(uid)
                }
            }
            reader.close()

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            statusTextView.text = "Error reading CSV file"
        }
    }

    private fun checkUidInDatabase(uid: String) {
        if (validUids.contains(uid)) {
            statusTextView.text = "Entrée autorisée"
            statusTextView.setTextColor(getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark))
        } else {
            statusTextView.text = "Entrée non autorisée - voir CSB"
            statusTextView.setTextColor(getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark))
        }
    }

    // Check for permission to read external storage
    private fun checkPermissions() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
        } else {
            // If permission is granted, load the CSV
            loadCsvDatabase()
        }
    }

    // Handle the result of permission request
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted, load the CSV
                loadCsvDatabase()
            } else {
                // Permission denied, handle accordingly
                statusTextView.text = "Permission denied to read external storage"
            }
        }
    }
}

manifest :
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.simplicims">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="simpliCIMS"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SimpliCIMS">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="simpliCIMS"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"
                android:value="text/plain" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

i just want to put a NFC tag, and have a OK or NOK depending if the UID is in the database.
Nothing more but i failed every time.
I use AI because i'm not developper even i try to understand some things.

You cannot rely on the Tag UID of a Desfire NFC tag because this tag has a security option: it will respond with a RANDOM UID if configured, so your code might be useless. This option will be activated in a company usage, sorry.

WARNING: Trying to just use an NFC UID to authorise access as you seem to be doing is VERY insecure. NFC UID's are not guaranteed to be Unique. There is hardware easily available that can copy them and reasonably quickly brute force them.
That said one of the main problems is that your code is not looking for the right type of NFC Tag or actually looking for any type of NFC Tags at all.
There are a number of methods that can be used for your program to tell the Android NFC Service that when it sees a particular type of NFC Tag that it should send it to your App. Depending on if your App is already running or not and what launch mode it is running in and what other NFC Apps are installed.
You have used the NFC Manifest Intent filter to instruct the Android NFC Service to send data about the Tag to your App if it sees a Tag with a NDEF data record on it.
The problem is your Tag does not have a NDEF data record on it, thus your App will never be notified that your ISO14443-4 : Type A, Isodep has been presented.
Then you have used enableForegroundDispatch to tell the Android NFC Service that you are not interested in being notified about any NFC Tags because you have passed it all null parameters.
It's more normal to use Manifest Intent filters to start your App when a certain type of NFC Tag is presented if not already running and then use one of the 2 foreground systems to exclusively be notified when the right type of Tag is presented (the two foreground systems are enableForegroundDispatch or the better and newer enableReaderMode)
So to fix this first you need to use the correct Manifest Intent Filter for your Tag Type
Create an XML file resource in the <project-root>/res/xml folder called nfc_tech_filter.xml
In this file create a tech-list that matches your Tag details of being "NFC Type A" AND "NFC IsoDep" e.g.
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>


The edit your Manifest to use this XML file. e.g. change the meta-data element for your Activity.
<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
    android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />


You also need to change how you process your Intent
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
  super.onNewIntent(intent)
  processIntent(intent)
}

fun processIntent(intent: Intent?) {
  if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED == intent?.action) {
    val tag: Tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)!!
    val uid = tag.id.joinToString("") { it.toString(16).padStart(2, '0') }
    uidTextView.text = "UID: $uid"
    checkUidInDatabase(uid)
  }
}

// Then add to `onCreate` method 
//because the Intent might be delivered to onCreate instead of onNewIntent
processIntent(getIntent())



This is all in the Android NFC Documentation
To make enableForegroundDispatch work you need to give it a Pending Intent for it to deliver back the Tag data to you.
val intent = Intent(this, javaClass).apply {
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
}
var pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null)
// Should really set the nulls to a be a Tech filter for NfcA and IsoDep
// But this will match ALL Tags

Also in Android Documentation
Hopefully that would match your Tag (and be right because I normally on use the newer and better enableReaderMode and not in Kotlin)
